# Populating DbSet<TEntity>.Local with only specified fields

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Linq to Sql, I would download only a subset of fields for processing in order to reduce query time. Something like this...

```
var local_data = from row in context.MyTable
select new {
    ID = row.ID,
    Name = row.Name,
    EMAIL = row.EMAIL
};
```

And then I would simply convert the projected data into a POCO collection...

```
foreach(var item in local_data){
    collection.Add(
        new MyTable(){
            ID = item.ID,
            NAME = item.NAME,
            EMAIL = item.EMAIL
        };
    );
}
```

This is extremely useful when dealing with massive, unwieldly table records where I only want to pull a handful of columns. When I heard about `DbSet<TEntity>.Local`, I was eager to switch over from `Linq2SQL`, but I can't seem to find the version of this new streamlined caching system that allows me to narrow the query scope to specific columns. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> caching system that allows me to narrow the query scope to specific columns

Sorry, the answer is: not possible.

The reason is that EF's internal cache is used for tracking entities, *full* entities. Being able to access these cached entities through the `Local` collection is a mere bonus that was introduced with the `DbContext` API. The cache doesn't exist *because* of it. The cache is for change tracking.

When EF materialized an entity from the database, it stores its original values into the change tracker and also frequently stores copies of its current values. When it's time to save changes, these values are compared and SQL statements are generated accordingly to store the changes.

Now you know this, you'll understand that EF can't store party populated entities into its cache. How should EF carry out change tracking if an entity can have any random collection of original values and current values?

Also, the result of a *projection* -- `select new` -- is never tracked (cached) and, thus, not accessible through a `Local` collection.

So in *this* respect you won't gain much by moving to EF.

Comment: Interesting. When I cache data this way, it's usually a for the sake of compiling reports, or performing comparative analysis, but if `Local` is only meant for change tracking as you say, then it's probably best to handle most read-only operations separately. Thanks for the info.